# Question about proof of showing Cauchy Schwarz inequality implies Schwarz inequality from Spivak

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have a question about a proof about the Cauchy Schwarz inequality implying the Schwartz inequality. This question is from *Spivak's Calculus pg. 278*. The following screenshot is the question:

[image]

For reference the Schwarz inequality is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2}}$$

The primary way Spivak handles integrals in this section is using the Darboux definition of integrals. So using that idea I created the following inequalities:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \leq \int_{a}^{b}f^{2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \leq \int_{a}^{b}g^{2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$$

As well as:

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(fg)(t_{i} - t_{i-1})\bigg)^{2} \leq \bigg(\int_{a}^{b}fg \bigg)^{2} \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(fg)(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) \bigg)^{2}$$

Later on I was going to swap out the $f,g$'s with the appropriate $x_{i}, y_{i}$'s. This was just me doing my rough work.

From here I thought that there might be a way to compare the sets of inequalities with some manipulation. Specifically I figured if I multiplied the first set of equations together I end up with:

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \bigg) \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1})\bigg) \leq \bigg(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2} \bigg) \bigg(\int_{a}^{b}g^{2} \bigg) \leq \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \bigg) \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1})\bigg)$$

At this stage seeing things possibly coming along I thought I was on the right track, but my concern was the cross terms from the outer summations messing things up. Here is where my issues lies. I have a solution from Spivak's Answer book, the following is a screenshot of it:

[image]

How does that term $$\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$$ (same for $y_{i}$) actually come to be ?

I understand the $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ as being the product of the equally sized subintervals each of length $\frac{1}{n}$, but then getting $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ means that he multiplied those summations but there are a bunch of cross terms that do not cancel out, at least when I attempted to work it out. So where is the misunderstanding from my part coming from?  Everything else in the proof is clear and it would appear I was working towards those results, but that one part has me annoyed.

EDIT: My apologies, I described the wrong term initially. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your criticism of the $\tfrac{1}{n^2}$ factor. We have$$\int_0^1fgdx=\sum_i\int_{(i-1)/n}^{i/n}fgdx=\sum_i\int_{(i-1)/n}^{i/n}x_iy_idx=\sum_i\frac{x_iy_i}{n}=\frac1n\sum_ix_iy_i.$$It's a rather unfortunate typo on Spivak's part. We can fix this by multiplying each of $f,\,g$ by $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. But we don't need to, because we obtain the same inequality with or without this rescaling.

Comment: I made a slight mistake with regards to which cross term was confusing me. I'm not sure if it changes your solution any bit though.

Comment: @dc3rd Technically, the term with $x_iy_i$ is the cross term, while the terms with $x_i^2$ or $y_i^2$ are diagonal terms. But no, this change in focus doesn't change my solution, because the diagonal terms are actually special cases of the cross term where $x_i=y_i$.

Comment: I notice in your proof there was no use at all of the upper or lower sums. Also the idea of "treating" $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$ as constants when you performed the integration.  Why are these tings possible?

Comment: I had a third question little question about rescaling. So I know of the relationship $\int_{ca}^{cb}f(t)dt = c \int_{a}^{b}f(ct) dt$. How did that get applied?

Comment: @dc3rd In this exercise, we prove a result concerning constants $x_i\,y_i$ from the $a=0,\,b=1$ special case of a result about functions, by choosing $f,\,g$ as the above definitions in terms of said constants.

Comment: AH...so in that definition of $f(x)$ the $x_{i}$ should be seen as a constant (same for $g(x)$). So to generalize in terms of math syntax should I always treat that scenario as such? i.e. if presented with $x_{i}$ they should be seen as constants? I suppose so because they are realizations of the "function" $x(i)$.  With regards to the rescaling, I was setting $c = \frac{i}{n}$. but as you can see for the lower bound of integration I end up having a problem.